# How to display the user avatar/image in the user account page using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

The image is uploaded by the user and stored in public/users folder. The view script is as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->render("includes/header.phtml"); ?>
<div id="header">
<div class="w">
    <div id="logo"><a href="/">SyncFan.com</a></div>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="/account/accountmanager"><span>My Account</span></a></li>             
            <li onMouseMove="$('.submenu',this).show();$(this).addClass('hover');"  onMouseOut="$('.submenu',this).hide();$(this).removeClass('hover');"><a href="/artist/list"><span>View Artists</span></a></li>
            <li onMouseMove="$('.submenu',this).show();$(this).addClass('hover');"  onMouseOut="$('.submenu',this).hide();$(this).removeClass('hover');"><a href="/account/update"><span>Update Account</span></a></li>
            <li onMouseMove="$('.submenu',this).show();$(this).addClass('hover');"  onMouseOut="$('.submenu',this).hide();$(this).removeClass('hover');">
                <a href="/account/logout"><span>Log Out</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="w">
<h2>SyncFan My Page - <?php $this->session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('login');echo $this->escape($this->session->username); ?></h2>
<!--- MAIN CONTAINER -->
<table class="table">
<tr><td valign="top">
<!--PROFILE DATA-->
<table class="table ">
<tr><td>Username: <?php echo $this->session->username; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="<?php echo '../public/users/'.$this->avatar; ?>"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $this->aboutme; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date Joined: <?php echo $this->session->dateJoined?></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<!--FAVORITE ARTIST LIST-->
<table class="table table-hover">
<?php if($this->artists){?>
<tr align="center">
<td><b>Artist Name</b></td>
<td><b>Date Became A Fan</b></td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($this->artists as $artist){?>
<tr>
<td><a href='/artist/video-list?artist=<?php echo
urlencode($artist['artist_name'])?>'>
<?php echo $this->escape($artist['artist_name']); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $this->escape($artist['date_became_fan']); ?></td></tr>
<?php }
}else{
?>
<tr><td>You currently have no favorite artists.</td></tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
<?php echo $this->render("includes/footer.phtml"); ?>
```

in the account view. 
The output of the HTML statement

```
<img src="<?php echo '../public/users/'.$this->avatar; ?>"/>
```

is empty.
I'm able to get the details of the uploaded image but not able to present it back to the user account.

```
<?php var_dump($this->avatar); ?>
```

The ouput of the above statement is string 'filename.jpg' (length=length of file).

I have checked the .htaccess file also but could not find anything wrong in it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src"<?php echo '/users/'.$this->avatar;?>"/>
```

The browser can't access anything outside your document root, which presumably is `/public`, so the path should be relative to that.

**Edit**: So the line from your template is:

```
<tr><td><img src="<?php echo '../public/users/'.$this->avatar; ?>"/></td></tr>
```

if you view the source of the resulting HTML page, you should get:

```
<tr><td><img src="../public/users/filename.jpg"/></td></tr>
```

(which won't work). With my suggestion above, the line from your template should actually be:

```
<tr><td><img src"<?php echo '/users/'.$this->avatar;?>"/></td></tr>
```

which should give you:

```
<tr><td><img src"/users/filename.jpg"/></td></tr>
```

If you are actually getting:

```
<tr><td><img src""/></td></tr>
```

then you've missed the 'echo'. If you're getting:

```
<tr><td><img src"/users/"/></td></tr>
```

then `$this->avatar` does not in fact contain filename.jpg like you said.

If the *entire page* is blank, there's actually a PHP error being generated but you have `display_errors` turned off (check your web server error log). Without knowing exactly what you are getting, all I can do is guess.

Comment: I have tried it but got the same result. So, can you please tell me where I have to look into.

Comment: If you view the HTML source what is the output? And what is the correct filename/path of the image?

Comment: The HTML output is empty. The path to the image is: 'C:\wamp\www\zendtest\syncfan\public\users'.

Comment: What's in `$this->avatar`?

Comment: If `$this->avatar` contains the image name and you are outputting it, how can the HTML output be empty?

Comment: That is what annoying me. I'm getting the details of the image correctly but I am not able to display the image on the user profile/account page.

Comment: But what you are saying is contradictory. Please edit your question to include the HTML output - the whole `<img>` tag, and also the output of `<?php var_dump($this->avatar); ?>`

Comment: What you are saying still dosen't make any sense - in what context does the image tag appear? Is it in a view script? If so please edit your question to include a few lines above and below it.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Tim Fountain. The change `<tr><td><img src"<?php echo '/users/'.$this->avatar;?>"/></td></tr>` has worked. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo '/users/'.$this->avatar; ?>"/>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```